# How to make Eclipse display Japanese symbols (kanji)?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project in Eclipse 3.4.1 where i would like to use Japanese symbols (like 象形文字).
The problem is that such symbols cannot be displayed correctly in Eclipse and i see black boxes instead of them.

I am using "Utf-8" encoding for all files.

Could anyone advise me how to fix this ?
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You have chosen a font in Eclipse capable of showing the characters in question?

The font selection is in the General section of the Preferences pane.

Answer (score 0):

To agree with the previous poster but explain a little more:  IF you are seeing boxes instead of random looking garbage strings, then Eclipse is decoding the characters properly, but your font simply doesn't have those chars available.

Answer (score 0):

Put / change this in eclipse.ini:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```