# What Font to Use to Display Japanese Characters in Eclipse Console Output?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Windows 7. In Eclipse, what font do I need to use to display Japanese characters in the console output?  All I see are boxes instead of kanji/hiragana/katakana, and according to [this SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10969413/739379), the boxes mean that Eclipse is encoding the text correctly and that the correct font to display the text is not installed.

Comment: i'm not sure font is the problem. take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965195/utf-8-cjk-characters-not-displaying-in-java

Answer (score 1):

I think MS UI Gothic 9 is a good choice.